# WebView on Android 11 - not showing local image files

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a problem with WebView on Android 11 (this worked under Android 10). The html

```
<img src='file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package>/image_cache/item_15.bmp'>
```

does not load the image. That html is part of a larger string. The image file was created by the same app and is valid.

What's changed?

Comment: You need to use base64 encoded data. See the [note on the Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: FYI, there's no need to add "solved" to your title - by marking the answer as accepted, you indicate that it's solved.  I've removed it for you.

Comment: FYI: The reason I do that _everywhere_ is that it makes it easier to see what has been solved. Please change it back!

Comment: Do not do it on Stack Overflow. If you want to mark your question as "solved", accept an answer (as you've already done).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);`. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setAllowFileAccess(boolean)) says:

> The default value is true for apps targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q and
> below, and false when targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.R and above.